WorkItem Creation Transaction Rollback
Is there a way to implement a rollback mechanism when creating work items in C#? I want the work items to be created only after the program finishes running successfully. If an exception occurs, the creation should be rolled back. Like i've written a program that reads workitems from a TFS and creates a new workitem accordingly in DevOps. but since there are around 100'000 WorkItems, i wanted to implement this, but don't know how.
i know that i can do something similar when working with a database but i don't know if it's possible to do this in this case.

Your own logic can catch exceptions and create work items only at the end of your try block, say create the new work item after you process the 100K items successfully. No need to "roll back" any created items.
If you're instead talking about iterating through the 100K and create a new one based on the processing of each one or some other tally then you'll have to keep track in a list and remove them with other API calls in your catch block.


Is there a way to implement a rollback mechanism when creating work items in C#?

I am afraid that the creation of work items cannot be rolled back.
After your program executes to read and create work items, the created work items can only be deleted but not rolled back when an exception is caught. But in this case, the work item ID that has already been used still cannot be reused after permanently delete.
Here is the API you can use to delete work items: Work Items - Delete
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?destroy={destroy}&api-version=7.1

